# Pdf text looks faded both on screen and on paper

Tags: formatting, color

Looking at the pdf generated from the latex code (I am using texmaker) it looks faded with respect to other pdf files I am use to read. I mean, the words are not as dark as the ones on the other papers.

The same happens when I print it.

How can I make them look darker? (I am not allowed to change the font)

Comment: What font are you using? If you are new to LaTeX and are using default Computer Modern, you may be surprised at how light this font is, especially on screen.

Comment: I have not set any font therefore it uses the default one. The requirements I have on the font say I must use the Times New Roman or similar and, according to your comment, the default one is not the Times although it looks quite the same.

Comment: The default font is the one the inventor of TeX, Donald Knuth, designed especially for this system. For a Times-like font, add to your preamble, `\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and compile with `pdflatex`.

Comment: Since I have .eps figure in the document can I still use pdflatex?

Comment: @Rhei Yes. The figures will be converted by `graphicx` and included automatically. However, you don't need to use `pdflatex`. You can use the packages suggested and use `latex`.

Comment: Ok, thank you. One last question: what is the difference between the `\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}` and the `\usepackage{times}`?

Comment: The `times` package loads Nimbus Roman No. 9 as the main text font; `newtxtext` loads Tex Gyre Termes. These are both siblings of Times New Roman in the same font family. `newtx` is more recent and is more focused on providing full math support. Enter `texdoc newtx` in a terminal (or use the documentation menus of TeXmaker) to learn more.